# WSO2 ESB and IS integration - handlers tag not supported

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Have a WSO2-ESB rest service which invokes another Rest Service.

On attempting to add OAuth based authentication to secure the called Rest service resource, i am not able to add the below snippet either from WSO2-Studio or the ESB Console

```
<handlers>
   <handler class="org.wso2.handler.SimpleOauthHandler"/>
</handlers>
```

[Here is the link to the example i am trying to follow](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Securing+REST+APIs#SecuringRESTAPIs-UsinganOAuthBaseSecurityToken)

**ScreenShot**

[image]

**SourceCode[wso2esb-4.6.0]:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="sampleAPI" context="/sample" hostname="10.203.101.76">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{str1}/{str2}">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="fn:concat('/customers/',get-property('uri.var.str2'))" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="full"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://echo.jsontest.com:80/key/value/"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <log separator=",">
                <property name="response" value="Starting response json message"/>
            </log>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
        <handlers>
       <handler class="org.wso2.handler.SimpleOauthHandler"/>
    </handlers>
</api>
```

Thanks,
Wajid

Comment: Did you can try with ESB sourceview?

Comment: **A Workaround** Opened the sampleAPI.xml in a text editor and make entries for <handlers>.Deploy and you will see OAuth in action.    However you will not see this entry when you open the sampleAPI.xml using eclipse graphical editor or the ESB Console source view.

Comment: What version of ESB you are using?

Comment: ESB version : wso2esb-4.6.0

Comment: seems then a bug! Reported https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Issue has been fixed and it will be available from WSO2 ESB 4.7.0

Thank you,
Best regards,
vanji